# Android Launcher not working

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-4.2-jelly-bean, launcher, google-cloud-messaging

I created a launcher on Android and it was working fine, until I tried to include Google Cloud Messaging into my launcher.

Normally when I am trying this kind of stuff I backup my previous application which I did in this case too.

The application with the GCM modules was crashing so I went back to the previous application built it and installed on the Device.

This time however my launcher wouldn't even launch. I have uninstalled the previous version (tried it many times) I also tried factory reset but it wouldn't work.

Does the device maintain some files even after factory reset or uninstall which I need to delete from the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of ABD to get into the device and execute a set of shell commands to make sure that the files are removed. You need to first check if the files that you suspect are causing the crash are still present.

Please have a look at this [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to know more about the ADB commands that you would need to check if the files are present and needs to be removed.

You can always use the `adb shell ls` to get the list of available shell commands. `rm` would be specific to remove a specific file from the system.

Internal Storage

You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Your issue might be specific to device if rooted or not rooted as you have tagged 4.2-Jelly beans and also try to run your app in the target sdk version you have specified in your maifiest.